# Google Cloud function wanting a PORT to listen to

Tags: function, cloud

I'm writing a Cloud function to simply get an oauth token and write it to a firebase. My code works until I include

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();
```

I'm including `"firebase-admin": "^9.8.0"` in my dependencies on the `package.json`.

Once I include the code above, I'm getting a error on deployment:

```
Could not create or update Cloud Run service oauthhandling2, Container Healthcheck failed. 
Revision 'oauthhandling2-00012-wim' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided 
container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 
environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

Not sure if that makes sense since I'm in a function that should be trigger with https call and not listen ot a port. Also, it works if I don't use firebase-admin.
Any thoughts? I shouldn't be asked for a port to listen to since it's cloud function and it's triggered with https calls, I believe.